# Profiler slef and total time difference

Tags: matlab

I am working on some in which the speed and time are of high importance. I am using `profiler` to find the bottleneck of my code, but i cannot understand some things in `profiler`.

first, what does self and total time mean?

second, it has something called `workspacefunc>local_min` and `workspacefunc>local_max`, what are they?

Answer (score 2):

`self` time is the total time spent in a function, not including any spent in any child functions called.  As an example, if you had a function which was calling a whole bunch of other functions, the `profiler` only includes the time spent in the main function called from the `profiler` and **not** in any of the other functions defined inside the main function.

`total` time is the total time spent on a function (makes sense, right?).  This includes the timing in all of the child functions called.   Also, you need to be careful where the `profiler` itself can take some time to execute as well, which is included in the results. One small thing as well: the total time can be **zero** for functions whose running time are inconsequential.

Reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html

---

`workspacefunc`... there doesn't seem to be any documentation on it, but this is the `help` text that I get when checking what it does:

```
workspacefunc  Support function for Workspace browser component.
```

The Workspace browser is a window that shows you all of the variables that are defined in your workspace.  If I were to take an educated guess, `profiler` does some analysis on your workspace variables, which include the `min` and `max` of certain variables in your workspace.  I can't really say much more as there is absolutely no documentation on this, but it's safe to ignore.  Simply focus on the functions that you are calling from your own code.

Comment: you mean I am calculating some `min` and `max` for some variable?! but i don't do that!

Comment: @uder3482383 There may be other built in functions that you are calling the do this under the hood. As I said, the **profiler** may be doing stuff under the hood, and is calling those functions.  I didn't say you were calling them specifically!